# React 15 / Redux - update component after props changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a question about updating props. I have component connected to redux store. When root component did mount I call ajax request and update store. My connected component receive new props but it doesn't re-render (there's no options). I know I can update internal state of my connected component but... is it necessary?

componentWillReceiveProps

```
receive props
 {agreements: Array(4), actions: {…}} //nextProps
 {agreements: Array(0), actions: {…}} //this.props
```

Click refresh button

```
refresh {agreements: Array(4), actions: {…}} //this.props
```

My connected component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as agreementActions from '../../actions/agreementActions';

class ChangeAgreement extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.refresh = this.refresh.bind(this);
    }

    refresh()
    {
        console.log('refresh');
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        console.log('receive props');
        console.log(nextProps);
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    render() {
        const { agreements } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                Pick agreement
                <button onClick={this.refresh}>Refresh</button>
                <select>
                    {agreements.map((item) => {
                        <option value={item.ID}>{item.NM}</option>;
                    })}
                </select>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        agreements: state.agreements
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(Object.assign({}, agreementActions), dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChangeAgreement);
```

Comment: I found a bug. I map agreements in a wrong way. Component update props as I expected :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arrow function

```
agreements.map((item) => {
                        <option value={item.ID}>{item.NM}</option>;
                    })
```

returns `undefined`. You forgot to `return`.